# savon ruby colon inside hash

Tags: ruby, hash, savon

Is it possible somehow in Ruby to write in hash something like this:

```
"xmlns:soap"
```

So it will something like

```
:xmlns:soap
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:"xmlns:soap"
```

will create a `Symbol` out of your `String`, regardless of the containing characters. This is the same as writing:

```
"xmlns:soap".to_sym
```

Answer (score -1):

`No` anything between the double quotes `"` is a string/ So it will not allowed.

However you can do something like following

```
{value: :abc} # this will produce {:value=>:abc}
```

Note:- above code will work only for Ruby 1.9.3 for older versions write simply

```
{:value=>:abc}
```

Comment: That's not exactly true. You has `:'your string'` syntax that is syntactic sugar to `'your string'.to_sym` and he will get what he want.